# Adding/Revising comments for Area 51 Commitment Phase after commiting

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, area-51, commitment-phase

Yesterday, I saw that some of the proposals I am following on Area 51 went into the commitment phase, so I quickly committed to them, as I want to participate in them. Unfortunately, as I am currently traveling, I was unable to write a comment for each commitment at the time.

My questions are:

- Does not including a comment affect my possibility of participating in the betas of those sites?
- Can I somehow add a comment now (or revise my "no comment" comment)? I'm considering the possibility of uncommitting and then recommitting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Allowing users to add/edit their comments after the fact sounds like a reasonable idea.

The comment does not affect your ability to participate in the Beta phase. *Anyone* can participate in the beta phase. It's public.

For now, un-committing and re-committing should take care of your immediate concern.

Answer (score 0):

I urge every one committing to leave a commit comment, explaining ...

> Why are you supporting this site, and how will you contribute to it?

That really does help the community figure out which sites are going to succeed, and why.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question. The OP is trying to do exactly that.